# Uma consulta com respostas relacionadas

Tags: php, javascript, sql, ajax

Grande prazer estar aqui.

Gostaria de uma informação. Qual seria a forma ou o nome mais correto para fazer uma ferramenta assim:

Eu gostaria de fazer um filtro no banco de dados utilizando caixas de seleção no front. Onde que eu seleciono 4  caixas do mesmo banco e me retorne os resultados das linhas relacionadas.

Como se fosse o filtro do Excel.

Já tenho acesso ao banco sql . Já importei o Excel com CSV   falta apenas os relacionamentos das primeiras colunas e os resultados

[image: esboço do projeto que pretendo criar]

Comment: Você precisa pegar o valor dos filtros, e usar no PHP criando um query para o bando de dados usando esse valores em um SELECT. E tente mostrar algum código que já tenha feito, fica mais fácil de responder a pergunta.

Comment: basicamente é um filtro simples, mas qual exatamente a dúvida? tem a parte de frontend (javascript) e backend (php/sql), o que já tem de código e qual a dúvida?